# Transparent Eclipse Splash Screen in Deployable Feature

Tags: java, eclipse, pde

I want to customize the splash screen of an `eclipse` were my `Deployable Feature` is installed.

I do not want to export a RCP - only a `Deployable Feature`.
Setting another `SplashScreen-Image` works fine, as long as it is a file called "splash.bmp" within my "product"-plugin (where I'm trying to handle all the branding stuff). Unfortunately, the bmp file format does not support transparency.

I already went through lots of examples and documentations, but without success yet.
Is that even possible?

Comment: according to wikipedia bmp supports [transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but i doubt that bmp supports Alpha-Channels  - unfortunately.
I tried it but Gimp saves it as png automatically when selecting "include alpha channels". When forcing Gimp to save it as *.bmp the background is white.

Comment: found a bmp image with a supposed transparent background and put it on my project. Transparency was not applied anyway (the color defined as transparent was shown, in this case a bright magenta)

Answer (score 1):

It's currently (Nov. 2022) not possible from what I can find

See [related bug report from 2021-08-17: [launcher] Explore Splash screen support for transparent background images.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575452).

And the related discussion in this ticket: [[launcher] Splash screen support for other image formats](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=114567)

Comment: @Adriaan The title and date of creation for first linked ticket covers most information. The second ticket is ~18 years of background information, and difficult to summarise. Can you give an example of a good answer in a situation like this? I guess I can verbatim copy-paste the first ticket's comments, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: After reading through the discussion and bug report, I retract my comment. You're right. It's a bug and all you can say here is that it was first discovered in 2005, the bug report created in August 2021 and hasn't been fixed, i.e. it's not possible. There's indeed not much more to add in this case. Apologies.